# Update Button VBA Code in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to Update the data based on combo box selection in an Access form. I'm looking for Update Button VBA code. Please help me on this.
[image]

Comment: Need additional info. What exactly is "data"?

Comment: I have to pick my Permit number from the 1st combo box and update the status from a 2nd combo box.(Closed,Open,Extended)

Answer (score 0):

Place this on the `Click` event of your Update button and replace *"Your…"* with the actual name.

```
Private Sub YourUpdateButtonName_Click()
    Dim sql_ As String
        sql_= "UPDATE YourTablename " & _
              "SET [Status]='" & Me.YourStatusControlName.Value & "' " & _
              "WHERE [Permit Number]='" & Me.YourPermitNumberControlName.Value & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql_, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I placed your suggested code. The values are not updated. even isn't throwing errors.

Comment: Private Sub Command9_Click()
    Dim sql_ As String
        sql_ = "UPDATE dbo_access_control_permit " & _
              "SET [permit_status]='" & Me.Combo3.Value & "' " & _
              "WHERE [permit_no]='" & Me.Combo0.Value & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql_, dbFailOnError
End Sub

Comment: The SQL command is correct. Check the event is firing, on the button's On Click event you should have an `[Event Procedure]`. Check the combo controls name as well.